# Output Minecraft Server Info from TCP packages

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

I found this working Code in a german [forum](https://minecraft-server.eu/forum/threads/aktuelle-spieleranzahl-per-php-script-auf-server-website-anzeigen-lassen.3901/):

```
<?php
    $fp = fsockopen('176.9.59.135', 25565, $errno, $errstr, 4) or die('Verbindung fehlgeschlagen!');
    fwrite($fp, "\xFE");
    $answer = fread($fp, 256);
    if ($answer[0] != "\xFF") {
       die ('Anfrage fehlgeschlagen!');
    }
    $text = substr($answer, 3);
    $text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'auto', 'UCS-2');
    $parts = explode("\xA7", $text);
?>
<?php echo $parts[0] . ' (' . $parts[1] . '/' . $parts[2] . ')'; ?>
```

The result shows how many players are online.
I want to know what happens in Line 3,4 and 5:

```
 fwrite($fp, "\xFE");
 $answer = fread($fp, 256);
 if ($answer[0] != "\xFF") {
```

Where do I know what i need to Write into the socket (like at line 3)?
I sniffed with wireshark the Result Package with all the Informations...
How is it possible to echo the Data like Wireshark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `fwrite()`, you are writing some content to a handler. In this case, you are writing to a socket connected to a server. `xFE` is a hexadecimal `FE` value (this is 254 in decimal).

Then you call `fread()`. This reads the response associated with the handler. In this case, you are reading the server's response data.

```
if ($answer[0] != "\xFF") {
  die ('Anfrage fehlgeschlagen!');
}
```

This code checks if the first byte of the server response data is not `FF` (255 in decimal). If the server sends, for example, `0F` then the process ends `(die())`;

I am not familiar with Minecraft Server status, but my suggestion is to check if [this class](https://github.com/FunnyItsElmo/PHP-Minecraft-Server-Status-Query) works. The code is documented.

Comment: Okay thank you for your answere!
I know this Class, but there isnt much information about the hexadecimal Values. I will try to find out more with Google :( :)

Comment: I Googled **minecraft server protocol**